# PhoneGap unable to getDuration() out of Media API, but other methods work

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm building out an audio media recorder/player with PhoneGap.  It's all working beautifully, but I've hit a wrinkle I can't seem to iron.

`my_media.play();` does indeed play the media w/o error in my Eclipse or XCode consoles which is why the alert that is showing a -1 is puzzling.  I expect `my_media.getDuration();` to return the duration of the file I'm attempting to play.

My try/catch block isn't throwing an error, I'm quite puzzled on this one.  [Here's the PhoneGap documentation on Media.getDuration()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.getDuration).

```
function playAudio() {

    $('#btnStopRecording').removeClass('ui-disabled');
    $('#btnPlayMessage, #btnStartStopRecording, #btnDeleteMessage, #btnAcceptUpload').addClass('ui-disabled');

    my_media = new Media(fullRecordPath,

        // success callback
        function () {
            $('#btnPlayMessage, #btnStartStopRecording, #btnDeleteMessage, #btnAcceptUpload').removeClass('ui-disabled');
            $('#btnStopRecording').addClass('ui-disabled');
        },

        // error callback
        function (err) {
            console.log("attempting to play fullRecordPath = "+fullRecordPath);
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err.code);
        }
    );

    var thisDuration;

    try{
        thisDuration = my_media.getDuration();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("attempting to get duration error code "+err.code);
        console.log("attempting to get duration error message "+err.message);
    }

    alert("we're about play a file of this duration "+thisDuration);

    my_media.play();

    // stop playback when the stop button is tapped
    $('#btnStopRecording').off('tap').on('tap',function()
    {
        my_media.stop();
        $('#btnPlayMessage, #btnStartStopRecording, #btnDeleteMessage, #btnAcceptUpload').removeClass('ui-disabled');
        $('#btnStopRecording').addClass('ui-disabled');
    });

    // if the user leaves the page, stop playback
    $('#pageRecordMessage').live('pagehide', function()
    {
        my_media.stop();
        $('#btnPlayMessage, #btnStartStopRecording, #btnDeleteMessage, #btnAcceptUpload').removeClass('ui-disabled');
        $('#btnStopRecording').addClass('ui-disabled');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The metadata for the media in question has not been loaded when you call my_media.getDuration(). In the documentation you referenced in your question the example code puts the getDuration call into an interval:

```
var timerDur = setInterval(function() {
    counter = counter + 100;
    if (counter > 2000) {
        clearInterval(timerDur);
    }
    var dur = my_media.getDuration();
    if (dur > 0) {
        clearInterval(timerDur);
        document.getElementById('audio_duration').innerHTML = (dur) + " sec";
    }
}, 100);
```

I would recommend doing something similar.

Comment: I have it like you into setInterval but still doesn't work. It returns always -1. What can be the reason? Because it is executing well. The file type can be the problem? I am using mp3

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me. Basically, play and immediately stop. It doesn't seem to take any time, seems like a decent workaround.

```
media.play();
media.stop();
var length = media.getDuration();
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is too old. But it is still relevant because many might have been facing this same problem.
Whenever nothing works I just do one thing, upgrade or downgrade the version. In this case I solved my problem by installing following version.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media@1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar problem in cordova for iOS. I was successfully able to record, play and stop audio but unable to get current position and total duration for audio file. So I added `my_media.release()` just after I was done finishing recording audio i.e. after `my_media.stopRecord()` and it worked like a charm. Earlier I was getting `-1` for `getDuration()` and `0` for `getCurrentPosition()`.

Hope it helps someone.