# Phonegap media getduration not working as intended

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to get the duration of a recording with the media api on phonegap. (version 3.3, media plugin version 0.2.9)
but the method media.getDuration doesn't get the correct value, it works this way:

the first record, after release, the method returns always -1,
after the next recording (with the same media object), the getduration method returns the time of the previous recording. if i do a playback after the recording, now the getduration method returns the correct timer.

I'm not sure what to do, i have tried to invoke play and stop when i need the duration. but with no success.

tried this too, no success :

[PhoneGap unable to getDuration() out of Media API, but other methods work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367593/phonegap-unable-to-getduration-out-of-media-api-but-other-methods-work)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PhoneGap unable to getDuration() out of Media API, but other methods work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367593/phonegap-unable-to-getduration-out-of-media-api-but-other-methods-work)
Answer of brimil01 works.
The other answer just work on one of my device.

my code (you can doing something similar):

```
$cordovaMedia.play(media);
dur = $cordovaMedia.getDuration(media);
var counter = 0;
timerDur = setInterval(function() {
    counter = counter + 100;
    if (dur < 0) {
        dur = $cordovaMedia.getDuration(media);
    }
    $("#msg").html((counter / 1000).toMMSS() + "/" + dur.toMMSS());
    if (dur > 0 && counter / 1000 > dur) {
        $("#playAudio").css({
            'color': 'black'
        });
        $("#msg").html("Play finished.");
        clearInterval(timerDur);
        $cordovaMedia.stop(media);
        $cordovaMedia.release(media);
    }
}, 100);
```

same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712124/media-getduration-returns-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround:

Play the media (and then immediately pause it if you don't want to actually play it), before checking for the duration.